# buttons on toolbar too wide (android)

Tags: android, button, toolbar, android-wrap-content

I have two buttons on the toolbar which are not obeying the "wrap_content" layout_width directive. I have added green and red background colors to make their true widths apparent in the screenshot. I have padding set to 0dp and also no margins. I have looked in my brief styles.xml and see nothing relevant, and I haven't noticed anywhere else in the app which this is happening. Any tips would be appreciated.

Thanks.

[image]

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/pdf_renderer_toolbar"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/primaryColor"
    android:theme="@style/MyStyle"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Docs"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:background="@color/green_button_color"
        android:textColor="@color/solid_white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:id="@+id/pdf_docs_button"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Edit"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:background="@color/red_button_color"
        android:textColor="@color/solid_white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:id="@+id/pdf_edit_button"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Did you try removing style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"

Comment: Yes, but it made no difference in the width.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

add:

```
 android:minHeight="0dp"
 android:minWidth="0dp"
```

for both the buttons:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/pdf_renderer_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/MyStyle"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pdf_docs_button"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:background="@color/color_red"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:text="Docs"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/color_black"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pdf_edit_button"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:background="@color/color_green"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:text="Edit"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/color_black"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Suggest: LinearLayout, android:orientation="horizontal", with your Buttons with-in that layout.

Hope this helps :)